# Fetch googlesheet table to a html timeline

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

So the outcome: is to fetch data from a google sheet table (let's say 4 columns) into an html/js page with timeline, the moment I add a new row, the webpage will update a new timeline entry, without manually updating the html or hardcode it with data, is that possible?

Diagram attached for it

Googlesheet part could be replaced with something that convenient and easy to update just like it, no databases or similar.

Comment: I think it's the 'the moment I add a new row' part that may make this more difficult. Otherwise it's just a fetch/check of json data from the sheet every x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistake.
maybe you can try this code with used html

```
**<iframe src="URL"></iframe>**
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp